# Can I call a library function from a payable function?

Tags: solidity, library, payable

I seem to get a revert each time I try this. I'm unable to get any useful revert message from truffle, so any assistance there might also help solve this.

I have a library:

```
library LibInterface {
  ...
  mine(address who){
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

which I call

```
contract MyContract {
  ...
  function mine(address who) public payable{
    s.mine(who);
  }
  ...
}
```

Removing the payable flag or simply not sending funds via truffle test will stop the revert. Removing the library call or simple calling another non-library contract also succeeds.

Any ideas? Is this disallowed? Why?

Comment: Definitively you are allowed to call libraries from payable functions. It is not this the problem.

Comment: Agree with @RickPark, the problem is somewhere else. If you take the sample code from https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#libraries and add payable to the function register, it works perfectly

Comment: Is there any condition inside the function you are calling in the library that might possibly be the source of the revert? Maybe a require that was not satisfied?

Comment: Does the library function happen to do something like `require(msg.value == 0)`?